# Requesting OAuth credentials with node

Tags: node.js, express, curl, oauth, payu

Im implementing PayU API with node.js. This is the request example for obtaining access token that is written in PayU´s documentation

```
curl -X POST https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=145227&client_secret=12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f'
```

It is a curl request , so it works well when it is sent from the command line, but I need to send it from express server. Any ideas how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request` module for making **HTTP** requests.
The first argument to request can either be a URL string, or an object of options.

**url**: The destination URL of the HTTP request

**method**: The HTTP method to be used (GET, POST, DELETE, etc)

**headers**: An object of HTTP headers (key-value) to be set in the request

Example.

```
var request = require('request');

options = {
    "method":"POST",
    "url": "https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize",
    "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  "body": "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=145227&client_secret=12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f"
}

request(options, function(err, res, body){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  const data = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(data.access_token)
});
```

Comment: Could you please show me how should I write the entire request please? I already tried it before, but I didn´t succeed , maybe  I did something wrong. This is the response I got ```body: '{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}' ```

Comment: Updated my answer. Working fine.